# Can be Solr-Spring-Data be adapted to the embbeded Lucene?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, spring-data, hibernate-search

I'd like to design a portable application that is using Spring with JPA, but doesn't deal with Hibernate to make it possible to easily to port it to Google Apps Engine. In case of data persistence everything can be designed well, while I don't see any "spring data way" to instrument the classes for embedded internal Lucene usage (i.e without using of Solr as external webservice on the different URL). So, i'd like to have the local Lucene embedded into my Spring app (that will make possible to replace it with Luceneappsengune implementation), while having all boilerplate code to be handled on the way it is done with solr-spring-data. Hibernate Search annotations also doesn't work for me in this case. Any thoughts, how to do it?

So in examples I see that the almost the only bean configured is

```
 @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    }
```

Why don't we have the similar adapter for the internally used Lucene?

Comment: There is no spring-data-lucene project. There is solr and elasticsearch maybe because most of the people are using solr or elasticsearch and rarely lucene directly.

Comment: is there a way to configure or substitute beans used for Lucene by embedded solr or elasticsearch to another Lucen Directory implementations? Say, GAE implementation. That would also work for me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can use Lucene as it is and create your own repository layer

Comment: yes, I can, but for spring-data approach is better for models extension; so if it would be a way configure a portability of embedded solr or elaticsearch to GAE once, it wouldn't require the updates on Lucene layer each time we need to extend models.